# Iterating over mount points on startup with python script executed as a service with systemd

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, python, systemctl

I want to iterate over mounting points with a Python script on a system startup.

The script works fine on the fully booted system (even when called as `sudo systemctl start launcher.service`) but fails to find mount points when started after reboot.

I guess the system needs some time to mount external devices on boot, and the script starts earlier than that, so I should change the service to execute after something.

My service now without AFTER in [Unit]:

```
[Unit]
Description=Python script executing after reboot.

[Service]
Type=simple
User=jetson
WorkingDirectory=/home/jetson/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/jetson/launcher_script.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What should I use in `AFTER=___` in systemd to launch the script on the system with already mounted drives? Or is there a more robust method to execute the script on the booted system automatically?

The problem is I don't know the mount point beforehand because Jetson mounts drives as `/media/jetson/9DC3-C264` or `/media/4A21-EE5D`. That's one of the reasons I wrote a Python script to iterate over mount points in search of the config file (and I can't mount it in `fstab` because it can be different drives/cards each time).

Python script looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import psutil
partitions = psutil.disk_partitions()

for p in partitions:
    if p.mountpoint != '/':
        #DO SOMETHING
```

My system is Ubuntu 18.04 on NVIDIA Jetson. And I want to add a possibility for updating my software or changing its parameters without user input or network from an external microSD card or USB drive. Also, I can not guarantee that drive will be mounted, and I want to start the script regardless.

Comment: Thanks for moving this to the right place. Given the `WantedBy=multi-user.target` - is this meant to be an IoT-thing, or are there interactive users?

Comment: It is more like IoT thing (there is monitor and GUI, but no user input, just to show processed camera feed)

Comment: So ... what kind of GUI are you showing, who owns the process?

Comment: Maybe if you use `Restart=on-failure` and `RestartSec=30` in `[Service]` section works